# Run docker command in bash file and run using crontab

Tags: bash, docker, cron

```
#!/bin/bash

docker exec -ti erpnext sh -c "cd /home/frappe/frappe-bench/ &&
/usr/local/bin/bench backup"

echo 'Hello, world.' >foo.txt
```

The above code is my bash file. 
Here have two command

1. create txt file
2. execute docker container

If I run this command

```
cd /home/arifur/workspace_python/erpdatabasebackup && bash backup_database.sh
```

in terminal then it is working

But when I run in crontab

```
* * * * * cd /home/arifur/workspace_python/erpdatabasebackup && bash backup_database.sh
```

then only txt file creation is working but docker container is not working.

Comment: "Not working" how? Is the Docker daemon not running? Can't your `cron` job connect to it? Or is the image you are trying to `exec` not running?

Comment: cd /home/arifur/workspace_python/erpdatabasebackup && bash backup_database.sh  this command is working in terminal.  So docker container is running

Comment: Which user runs those cronjob?

Comment: Instead of restating the things you already mention in the question, could you please respond to the things which are still unclear? Yes, it works in terminal. *How* does it fail from `crontab`?

Comment: @Cyrus, "Arifur" user

Comment: @tripleee,  docker command is not working at crontab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-ti` requests to use a pseudo-tty and run in interactive mode but cron does not attach to any TTY.  Try removing `-ti` as in

```
docker exec erpnext sh -c "cd /home/frappe/frappe-bench/ && /usr/local/bin/bench backup"
```